# How to get extract directory name from the full filepath name of a file using glob recursive

Tags: python, glob, dirname

I have two folders cats and dogs with 5 jpeg images in each
cat1.jpeg cat2.jpeg..... dog1.jpeg dog2.jpeg etc...

I want to write a CSV file that looks like this

1,./images/trainnew/dogs/dogs2.jpg,dogs
2,./images/trainnew/dogs/dogs1.jpg,dogs
3,./images/trainnew/cats/cats2.jpg,cats
4,./images/trainnew/cats/cats1.jpg,cats

Where entry dogs and cats at then end of each line refers to the name of the folders dogs and cats within the folder trainnew/

using the code below

```
from glob import glob
import os
count =1
f = open('test7.csv', 'w')
for filename in glob('./images/trainnew/**/*.jpg', recursive=True):    
    f.write(str(count) + ',' + filename + ',\n')
    print(filename) 
    count +=1
```

===================

My test7.csv looks like this

1,./images/trainnew/dogs/dogs2.jpg,
2,./images/trainnew/dogs/dogs1.jpg,
3,./images/trainnew/cats/cats2.jpg,
4,./images/trainnew/cats/cats1.jpg,

How do i get the respective directory names and print at the end of each of these lines respectively in the csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from glob import glob
import os

count = 1
with open('test7.csv', 'w') as f:
    for filename in glob('./images/trainnew/**/*.jpg', recursive=True):  
        dirname = os.path.dirname(filename)  # Get the directory name of the file
        foldername = os.path.basename(dirname)  # Get the base name from that directory path
        f.write(str(count) + ',' + filename + ',' + foldername + '\n')
        print(filename)
        count +=1
```

The `os.path.dirname(filename)` line retrieves the directory of the current file (like './images/trainnew/dogs' or './images/trainnew/cats'), and `os.path.basename(dirname)` give u the base name of that path (like 'dogs' or 'cats').

Comment: Thank you so much. I struggled for a day with this.